# Do .NET 2.0 API Calls Work on .NET 4.0 Runtime by Default, or Do They Require Extra Setup Steps?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, .net-2.0

If the C# frontend team on my project makes a standalone program that only does .NET 2.0 API calls, but install on to a computer with .NET 4.0, will it work by default or must they do something to the setup or to the setup-building process (like check off certain checkboxes) to make it work?

See, I'm assuming that if I make .NET 2.0 API calls only, that it should just "work" on .NET 4.0.

Part 2 on this is -- user has .NET 4.0 and .NET 1.1, but not .NET 2.0. I assume .NET 2.0 should work, then, because it has .NET 4.0. Right?

Background -- I'm a Linux/PHP dev and haven't touched C# since 2001. My skills are stale. The client's C# frontend team on my project need some assistance on understanding compatibilities, I guess, and so I've been asked by my client to ask this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET 2.0 should work if you have .NET 4.0 installed on your computer. I got this from this link: [Version Compatibility in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Keep in mind though, that some objects have changed from 2.0 and 4.0. They might not have all the same properties and methods. It is always a good thing to refer to the MSDN documentation.

Edit new link: Another good reference about the  element in the web.config/app.config file of your project: [supportedRuntime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4atty68%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes, a standalone app that talks to a Linux/PHP backend on a remote web server occasionally. Should have mentioned that.